# Can Orchard CMS run on .NET Framework 3.5?

Tags: .net, frameworks, orchardcms

I'm looking for a blog solution for my corporate website.  The rest of the site is run on the 3.5 framework, and Orchard builds run on 4.0.  Is there any way to rebuild from the source for 3.5, or is there an earlier version of Orchard that is built for earlier frameworks?

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Orchad requires MVC3, and MVC3 is incompatible with .NET 3.5, so no.. you can't use 3.5

Comment: This is correct. Quoting [the Developer FAQ](http://docs.orchardproject.net/Documentation/Developer-FAQ#WhatframeworkversionsdoesOrchardsupport?): 
Orchard currently supports the 4.0 version of the .NET framework.

Comment: That's what I keep coming up against - Thanks for confirming!

Comment: Orchard makes heavy usage of dynamic types so going back to 3.5 would be pretty impractical if not impossible.